# Project directory could not be found, restart Next.js in your new directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, next.js

I have a nextJS web app on a vps server with pm2 as my Process Management and no matter what I do, I can't get it to run properly! I have a deploy.js file that deploys it to the vps and it works with my other nextjs and reactjs apps but not this one.

First I tried having all the project minus a few files like the deploy file and the gitignore file to get uploaded then build on the vps, when it works it doesn't let me use the public directory (ex. Favicon and some images) or the environment variables from PM2.

Okay I did some searching to see what issues other people have had with and none of the fixes for other developers worked for me.

So I tried to have it build and then just deploy the build, well uploading it takes roughly 25 minutes longer and it doesn't use the correct environment variables from PM2 or my local system.

`error - Project directory could not be found, restart Next.js in your new directory`

NodeJS 18.13.2

NextJS 13.1.1

PM2 5.2.0

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out NextJS uses .env.local as an override and I need to make it .env.development.local and .env.production.local as stated [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)